# How to render single instance of Child to an items map within a Parent component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

How, in the functional Parent component below, would you adjust this to only appendChild, the Child component, to the particular div in the items map that is clicked, and not all the five divs of the items map onClick? Currently if you click the div, each div renders a Child component. The intent here is to only render a single instance of Child to the particular div that is clicked. For example, if `div id='one'` is clicked, `<Child />` should only append to that div.

```
const Child = () => {
  return (
    <div>Child</div>
  )
}

const Parent = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])
  const [child, setChild] = useState(<></>)

  useEffect(() => {
    setItems([
      'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'
    ])
  }, [])

  const appendChild = () => {
    setChild(<Child />)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(item => {
        return (
          <div
            id={item}
            onClick={appendChild}
          >
            {item}
            {child}
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Parent
```

Comment: what is that particular div condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove child state and add a clickedItems state which contains the items which were clicked on and render the child component if the item has been clicked. this is one possible way.

```
const Child = () => {
  return <div>Child</div>;
};

const Parent = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [clickedItems, setClickedItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setItems(["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index} id={item} onClick={() => setClickedItems((prevValue)=> [...prevValue, item])}>
            {item}
            {clickedItems.includes(item) && <Child />}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```